# Entity Framework - Oracle or Mysql from SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

Using Entity Framework with a database-first approach. I have few complex stored procedures, with `#temp` table in SQL Server, with create and drop on it .

My question is: do we need to re-write the stored procedures in MySQL or Oracle?

Please help .

Comment: **YES!** All procedural code is **heavily vendor-specific**, so a T-SQL stored procedure **cannot** run in neither Oracle nor MySQL - it needs to be rewritten / adapted for those procedural languages in those RDBMS systems

Comment: Thanks . As need to rewrite the SP , think ODBC wll be faster than entity framework . what do u think ?

Comment: Maybe faster at runtime, but **a lot less productive** at development time! Ditch ODBC - it's long gone, dead, legacy - use Entity Framework !